# SAXParseException: Element type SOAP:Text must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>"

Tags: exception, soap, sax, fault

I'm attempting to read a response from a web service call in a junit test running in Eclipse Galileo.  I'm able to successfully receive responses except when the response is a SOAP fault.  Then I get the following exception:
**org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Element type "SOAP:Text" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>"**

I have validated the XML in LiquidXML Studio against the SOAP 1.2 schema and it checks out.

Here is the XML response that SAX appears to be choking on.  It has been stripped to the minimum in an attempt to eliminate anything obvious (I even made sure it didn't have any self closing elements):

`<SOAP:Envelope xmlns:SOAP="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:SOAP_ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
    <SOAP:Header>
    </SOAP:Header>
    <SOAP:Body>
        <SOAP:Fault>
            <SOAP:Code>
                <SOAP:Value>SOAP:Sender</SOAP:Value>
                <SOAP:Subcode>
                    <SOAP:Value>SOAP:Sender</SOAP:Value>
                </SOAP:Subcode>
            </SOAP:Code>
            <SOAP:Reason>
                <SOAP:Text xml:lang="">
                </SOAP:Text>
            </SOAP:Reason>
            <SOAP:Node>
            </SOAP:Node>
            <SOAP:Role>
            </SOAP:Role>
            <SOAP:Detail>
            </SOAP:Detail>
        </SOAP:Fault>
    </SOAP:Body>
</SOAP:Envelope>`

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Its obviously not regcognising 'xml:lang=""' as an attribute. CHeck with your xsd or xmlSchema what attributes are valid. Also you should be using

```
xml:lang=&quot;&quot;
```

rather than "" although most parsers forgive you for this.

Comment: The schema referenced in the Envelope does include the xml:lang attribute for the Text element, which is why I mentioned validating against the schema in LiquidXML Studio. The valid responses and the SOAP fault include the quote character, so I know that's not a problem. Thanks for the resoponse.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in mapping the soap fault xml to its corresponding object.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what is mapping to what here?  It appears to be a straight schema validation or invalid character issue at first glance.  Thanks.

Comment: Usually when you get xml back, you need to convert it back to an object using your schema. so your xml data, xml schema and object need to be in sync for the parsing to work. Also your xml schema needs to be able to handle the proper response as well as the soap fault (which is tricky sometimes).

Comment: The process doesn't include objects at this point.  I'm just wanting to get back the string response to examine it.  I've dealt with SOAP faults before, but not with the SAX parser, and never had a problem.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the problem was related to a tool I was using to return static string responses to web service requests.  The static response XML contained the xml:lang attribute.  However, when the tool was returning the static string, it was modifying it on the way out and replacing xml:lang on-the-fly with the fully qualified namespace equivalent {http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace}lang.  When this response was received, the SAXParser was choking because it couldn't interpret the fully qualified equivalent.

The tool returning the static responses used a Groovy xml parser as an integral part of sending the response.
The XmlParser Groovy class has a constructor that I had to change to set validating and namespaceAware attributes to false.  So instead of XmlParser(), the tool now calls XmlParser(false, false).
Problem solved.
Thanks for the responses.